# NX how to use an interface library in frontend and backend

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I'm trying to migrate our repository to a mono repository managed by nx. The frontend is written in angular and the backend uses nodejs / express.
In the beginning, I want to use the same interfaces in both.

For that, I created a new workspace (Integrated Monorepo, not sure if this is the best choice):

```
npx create-nx-workspace
```

In the new workspace, I added a frontend and backend app:

```
npm install @nx/angular 
nx g @nx/angular:app frontend 
npm install @nx/express 
nx g @nx/express:app backend
```

I understand, that libraries are used for reusable code in nx. So my idea was to generate a library for interfaces.

```
npm install @nx/workspace
nx generate @nx/workspace:library lib-interfaces
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to resolve @nx/workspace:library.
>
> Cannot find generator 'library' in
>
> .../workspace/node_modules/@nx/workspace/generators.json.

For that, I didn't find any reason or solution, but I figured out, that I can use @nx/angular for that:

```
nx generate @nx/angular:library lib-interfaces
```

**So my Questions are:**

1. Is this library useable by express (because it is generated by @nx/angular)?
2. How I can use the library in angular and express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a library for interfaces in an Nx workspace using the following command:

```bash
npx nx generate @nrwl/js:library lib-interfaces
```

It will ask you about the testing library you want to use and how you want to build it. Usually `jest` and `tsc` is what you need.

You can also run the command with the flat `--dry-run` to test the output without affecting your repository.

When you create a library, the root `tsconfig.base.json` file is updated, particularly the `path` object inside the `compilerOptions` key.

You will find a new line like the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "@organization-name/api-interfaces": ["libs/api-interfaces/src/index.ts"]
    }
}
```

So you can use it like the following:

```js
import {Whatever} from '@organization-name/api-interfaces';
```

Comment: by that I was able to generate a new lib. but how can I use this in angular and express?